# Rails precompilation: how to skip certain file types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, sprockets, webpacker

I've been investigating some asset compiling issues for our app and I've been encountering this weird thing.

It seems that the rails app,when running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, is still writing a lot of javascript files. Here's an excerpt:

```
INFO -- : Writing /[some path]/public/assets/packs/reactapp-8d537cdb655e367c2557d2bd4f691a7056b318930c822aee42bb1fbc20533a83.js
INFO -- : Writing /[some path]/public/assets/video-thumb-082a5744955665d1553a0a018770c5fb5fc8fcb8bf108b804c4eb60765da4aed.png
INFO -- : Writing /[some path]/public/assets/visa-599fcb6beaeb6d9fd21df3dcabc42eb01d89cb3907860ed96bab0b0aeb0b79bc.png
INFO -- : Writing /[some path]/public/assets/components/IconSpacer-ca951c3d90e885b394225189b264cba9729606ffe620ea308a3f87f0d902f3e7.jsx
INFO -- : Writing /[some path]/public/assets/components/ToolbarButton-d7cb37546156ceda11c3e7b9591f37edd964df87a68a2d5b1347c1c8970d7170.jsx
INFO -- : Writing /[some path]/public/assets/components/archive/ArchiveListItem-433c52b7df01bab755574962478f0dbf862f5eeb742747a775b4fe872281003f.jsx
```

It's touching what seems to be all javascript files, even the `packs` folder. But because we're using Webpacker, these files shouldn't be touched by the rails asset pipeline at all, just become part of one of the bundles output by Webpack.

What would be the best way to tell rails/sprockets to ignore these files?

Comment: Your js files are in `app/assets/javascript` or `app/javascript` folder? Are you using `javascript_pack_tag` helper?

Comment: They're in `/app/assets/javascripts/`, and I'm using the new `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag`, but that's just Webpacker 4's `split-chunks`-friendly replacement of `javascript_pack_tag`

Comment: If I remember correctly, Webpacker only uses the files that are in `app/javascript` and not in `app/assets/javascript`, it's indicated in the "usage" section of the readme. Moving your files to `app/javascript/packs` should fix it

Comment: From the way you wrote your answer it seems like you didn't actually read what the question was. That said, it's possible that the issue surfaced because of the folder structure. We're using a rails 4 app, and rails 4's folder structure is slightly different than rails 5 which is what I assume the readme is made for. I guess moving the files might work, but that's something I'd rather not do now.

That said, the question remains the same. In the end, the issue is not with webpacker (which functions fine), but how to tell sprokets to ignore these files